# is it worth to store JSON into core data objects?

Tags: iphone, ios, json, core-data

I download a bunch of JSON objects in my app, and save the file as an nsdata object:

```
[responseData writeToFile:appFile atomically:YES];
```

Then whenever I want some of the json object, I load that data, serialize, and filter.
By now, it works great.

And, I'm gonna start downloading new types of JSON objects (with different properties), from the web.

¿Should I start using core data, or continue this way (meaning, no problems doing this)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on the scale of objects you'll be writing and serializing. If there can by a dynamic amount of these objects..thus potentially being alot, you should probably Look more into Core Data as the option for Storage.